# Define class in Python

Tags: python, class

To my knowledge, the way we define a class is like the following code:

```
class Example:
    'fields: firstname, lastname'
    def __init__(self, fn, ln):
        self.firstname = fn
        self.lastname = ln
```

What if the first element is not a simple string? What if it is a list, how to define the class?

Comment: Did you try it? It works.

Comment: What do you mean by "first element"? The first argument, `fn`? Or the string `'fields: firstname, lastname'` (the "docstring")?

Comment: @Blckknght I mean "firstname", what if "firstname" is a list of strings and I want to call every strings. how to do it?

Comment: If `fn` is a list of strings, you can still assign it to `self.firstname` if you want. Attribute assignment doesn't care what the type of object is being assigned. It's only when you actually go to *use* `self.firstname` that it might matter, and since your `Example` class doesn't show any code using `self.firstname`, there's no way to guess what you want. If you need to turn a list if strings into a single string (for printing, perhaps), often you'll want to use `str.join`.

Comment: It's unclear what this question is asking!!!

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed, so it doesn’t really matter what kind of value you assign to a variable—or pass to an object constructor for that matter.

You can just pass whatever you want, and unless the underlying code enforces some type (by an explicit check, or by [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) usage), it doesn’t matter at all.

So in your case, if you call `Example(1, Example)`, then the first name will be the *integer* `1`, and the last name will be the *type* `Example` (not really useful but possible).

Comment: Thanks! But how to call the elements in the list? "self.firstname= fn", what if fn is a list?

Comment: The declaration of your class does not need to change at all. You just pass a different value. Accessing the object’s member will then give you whatever you passed in. E.g. `obj = Example(1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])`, then `obj.firstname` will give you `1`, and `obj.lastname` will give you the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Answer (score 0):

Same way. You don't define the variable type in Python, so there's no difference whether the type is a string or a list.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamically-typed language. If the first element is a `list`, it will be of type `list`. If your program is relying on an `Example` object having a string in `my_example.firstname`, you'll need to check that it's a string, with something like this:

```
if isinstance(fn, str):
    self.firstname = fn
else:
    self.firstname = 'John'
```